# How to add Tag Value to Elements/ Entities in Spark EA using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to port some data from Excel sheet into EA model. I have managed to build a model, However I want to add some tag values to the elements/entities I have created through VBA. I have used Geert Bellekens EAExcelimporter utility and modified/amended it to suit my requirements.I am however not able to extend it to add tagged values to Entities. Anyhelp in this regards shall be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Rahul.

Answer (score 0):

I have now managed to write code for this.

Public Function addOrUpdateElementTag(anElement As EA.element, Tagname As String, tagValue As String) As EA.taggedvalue
    Dim currentElementTag As EA.taggedvalue
    'update all tagged values with the given name
    'Dim parentPackage As EA.package
    'get the selected package
    'Set parentPackage = eaConn.getSelectedPackage()

```
For Each currentElementTag In anElement.TaggedValues
    If currentElementTag.name = Tagname Then
        currentElementTag.Value = tagValue
        Set addOrUpdateElementTag = currentElementTag
        currentElementTag.Update
    End If
Next
'no tagged value found, so create it
If addOrUpdateElementTag Is Nothing Then
    Set addOrUpdateElementTag = anElement.TaggedValues.AddNew(Tagname, "ElementTag")
    addOrUpdateElementTag.Value = tagValue
    addOrUpdateElementTag.Update
End If
```

End Function

Hope this will be helpful to someone in future.

Thanks,
Rahul.